# ForkJoin not working at listening multiple observables from multiple forms valueChanges

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I'm doing a page that contains three different forms using Reactive Forms. I'd like to listen at all of their changes and do some logic if they are all valid. I checked on the forum and saw that I had to use forkJoin. The problem is that the changes are called at each page loads but not firing up when my values changes.

```
forkJoin([
  of(this.thirdStepFormFirstContainer.valueChanges),
  of(this.thirdStepFormSecondContainer.valueChanges),
  of(this.thirdStepFormThirdContainer.valueChanges)
]).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('One of the three has changed');
});
```

valueChanges returns an Observable, the forkJoin shouldn't fire up when the page loads, only on changes.

Does someone know how I could solve this ?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: This is not how `forkJoin` should be used. It waits for multiple observables to complete. You're returning an array of observables that instantly complete (`of`), which themselves return the `valueChanges` observables. You're never subscribing to `valueChanges`.

Comment: So you want to listen to all 3 controls at the same time, and be notified when any 1 of the 3 changes. And you want to do this for the lifetime of the component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a subscription to fire when any one of the three form control's values change, you can use the `merge` function.

```js
merge(
  this.thirdStepFormFirstContainer.valueChanges,
  this.thirdStepFormSecondContainer.valueChanges,
  this.thirdStepFormThirdContainer.valueChanges
).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('One of the three has changed');
});
```

`merge` will listen for changes on all three form controls, and your subscription callback will be notified when any one of them emits a value change.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zm9du9